# Generate pairs from columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

What's the easiest way in Pandas to turn this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Class': [1, 2], 'Students': ['A,B,C,D', 'E,A,C']})
df

   Class Students
0      1  A,B,C,D
1      2    E,A,C
```

Into this?

[image: paired match]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's try `combinations`:

```
from functools import partial
from itertools import combinations

(df.set_index('Class')['Students']
   .str.split(',')
   .map(partial(combinations, r=2))
   .map(list)
   .explode()
   .reset_index())

   Class Students
0      1   (A, B)
1      1   (A, C)
2      1   (A, D)
3      1   (B, C)
4      1   (B, D)
5      1   (C, D)
6      2   (E, A)
7      2   (E, C)
8      2   (A, C)
```

Comment: Thank you, cs95 fro introducing me to functools partial.  From your experience, does this work faster that creating a lambda?

Comment: @ScottBoston Yes, there are two reasons - the first is, it is never slower than a lambda (and can be faster sometimes). The second is, it just looks so much cleaner, it's great. :D

Comment: Great.  I am going to add this to my toolbox.  I appreciate your response.  Be safe and stay healthy.

Answer (score 4):

This need multiple steps with `pandas` only , `split` + `explode` , then `drop_duplicates`

```
df.Student=df.Student.str.split(',')
df=df.explode('Student')
df=df.merge(df,on='Class')
df[['Student_x','Student_y']]=np.sort(df[['Student_x','Student_y']].values, axis=1)
df=df.query('Student_x!=Student_y').drop_duplicates(['Student_x','Student_y'])
df['Student']=df[['Student_x','Student_y']].agg(','.join,axis=1)
df
Out[100]: 
    Class Student_x Student_y Student
1       1         A         B     A,B
2       1         A         C     A,C
3       1         A         D     A,D
6       1         B         C     B,C
7       1         B         D     B,D
11      1         C         D     C,D
17      2         A         E     A,E
18      2         C         E     C,E
```